# At runtime created self signed certificate doesn't work if not exported and reinstanced in netcore (3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

Can someone explain why the following certificate only works with aspnetcore if it is "exported" and "reinstanced"?

Please look at the return line of the *CreateSelfSignedServerCertificate* what I mean with export and reinstanced .

If one switches out the return value of function *CreateSelfSignedServerCertificate* to the "non-exporting" line accessing any https uri from the server throws

*No credentials are available in the security package*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = CreateSelfSignedServerCertificate();
            var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

            IHost host = builder
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
                {
                    o.ListenAnyIP(5555, o2 =>
                    {
                        o2.UseHttps(cert);
                    });
                });
            })
            .Build();
            host.Run();
        }

        static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedServerCertificate()
        {
            SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder sanBuilder = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
            sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.Any);
            sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.Loopback);
            sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.IPv6Loopback);
            var addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(t => t.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToList();
            addresses.ForEach(t => sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(t));
            sanBuilder.AddDnsName("localhost");
            sanBuilder.AddDnsName(Environment.MachineName);

            X500DistinguishedName distinguishedName = new X500DistinguishedName($"CN=localhost");

            RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
            {
                CertificateRequest request = new CertificateRequest(distinguishedName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

                request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                    new X509KeyUsageExtension(
                        X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment
                        | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment
                        | X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));

                request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                   new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
                       new OidCollection { new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }, false));

                request.CertificateExtensions.Add(sanBuilder.Build());

                X509Certificate2 certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(
                    new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)), new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(30)));
                certificate.FriendlyName = "localhost";

                return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx)); // exporting cert works with aspnetcore
                //return certificate; // non exported cert doesn't work with aspnetcore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For your code , it just create the certificate and it is saved in memory. If you want use it , you should export the generated certificate as a physical file and then  import the file into Certificate Manager which is a certificate management tool that stores the certificate .

Comment: maybe it is not clear but please look at the return value of CreateSelfSignedServerCertificate methode. With the current return line the Cert works, but not with the out-commented return value. 
So the memory only version works, but only with the first return value.

Comment: @Henk I would hazard to guess you are running on Windows. Most of the c# crypto API is typically a wrapper around some COM APIs in Windows or OpenSSL on *nix-based OSes. With COM APIs depending on your Windows versions and capabilities available, the machine may generate the keys in hardware and they are not available in your `X509Certificate2` object unless you say 'export' which causes the underlying storage to relinquish them to your managed code.

Comment: I looked at MSDN to see if you can indicate to `CreateSelfSigned` that this is what you want and there doesn't seem to be any, so it is likely correct what you're doing, with the understanding however that since you keep generating them you will eventually run out of space on this machine.

Comment: i don't think it is stored in the certificate store of windows, because I checked both certmgr and certlm and i couldn't find them there. So space shouldn't be a problem